# PID of com.apple.Dock.agent to send SIGHUP

Tags: objective-c, macos, macos-carbon, core-foundation

I'm trying to send a message of `SIGHUP` to the dock. To do this i need the PID of `com.apple.Dock.agent`, is there anyway to get this from objc or corefoundation?

Thanks

Comment: You should probably access it through `launchctl` since it's an `agent`.

Comment: Thanks i'm very unfamiliar with that, do you know a library that exports that function? Would it be `/usr/lib/system/liblaunch.dylib`?